# How to delete from an object

Tags: python, class, object, containers

```
import pickle

class TasksError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self.value)

class Task(object):
    def __init__(self, task = () ):
        if task ==():
            raise TasksError('Empty task.')
        self.name = task[0]
        self.date = task[1]
        self.priority = task[2]
        self.time = task[3]
        self.type = task[4]
        self.comment = task[5]

    def __str__(self):
        output = '''Name: %s
Date: %s
Priority: %s
Time: %s
Type: %s
Comment: %s
''' % ( self.name,
        self.date,
        self.priority,
        self.time,
        self.type,
        self.comment)
        return output

class Tasks(object):
    def __init__(self, container = []):
        self.container = [ Task(todo) for todo in container ]




    def delete(self):

        x = 0
        for todo in self.container:

             x = x + 1
             print "Task Number",x,"\n", todo
             delete = raw_input("what number task would you like to delete")
             if delete == "y":
                 del todo


        ############
        #x = 0
       # for task in self.container:
           # x = x+1
           #print "Task Number",x,"\n", task
            #delete = raw_input("what number task would you like to delete")
            #if delete == "y":
                #del(task)







    def add(self, task):
        if task == '':
            raise TasksError('Empty task')
        self.container.append( Task(task) )






    def __str__(self):
        output = '\n'.join( [ str(todo) for todo in self.container ] )
        return output

if __name__== "__main__":
    divider = '-' * 30 + '\n'



    tasks = Tasks( container = [] ) # creates a new, empty task list

    while True:
        print divider, '''Make your selection:
1. Add new task
2. Print all tasks
3. Save tasks
4. Load tasks from disk
5. Find high priority tasks
6. Sort by date
7. Delete task

<ENTER> to quit
'''
        try:
            menu_choice = int(input("Select a number from the menu: "))
        except:
            print 'Goodbye!'
            break

        if menu_choice == 1:

            task = raw_input (">>> Task: ")
            date = raw_input (">>> Date as string YYYYMMDD: ")
            priority = raw_input (">>> Priority: ")
            time = raw_input (">>> Time: ")
            Type = raw_input (">>> Type Of Task: ")
            comment = raw_input (">>> Any Comments? ")
            todo = (task, date, priority, time, Type, comment)

            tasks.add( todo )
            print tasks
        elif menu_choice == 2:
            print divider, 'Printing all tasks'
            print tasks
        elif menu_choice == 3:
            print divider, 'Saving all tasks'
            tasks.save()
        elif menu_choice == 4:
            print divider, 'Loading tasks from disk'
            tasks.load()
        elif menu_choice == 5:
            print divider, 'Finding tasks by priority'
            results = tasks.find_by_priority(priority='high')
            for result in results: print result
        elif menu_choice == 6:
            print divider, 'Sorting by date'
            tasks.sort_by_date()
            print tasks
        elif menu_choice == 7:

            tasks.delete()
```

I have deleted parts of my code (hopefully nothing important).
Im having trouble getting python to delete my tasks once added. 
Both methods defined as "def delete" give the error message type error: task/todo object does not support deletion. 
Does anyone know a way around this?

Comment: I had a look at this but im unsure how 2 implement it as I have not used it before

Comment: Make sure your indentation is correct when posting Python code. Your `delete()` function is indented wrong (this causes a syntax error, so I assume it's a mistake when copying).

Comment: sorry! it was a mistake, same errors though

Comment: Your mixing your task management with your IO.  This is bad program design.  See the difference between [coupling and cohesion](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29#section_5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't delete from list like that... Your code have 2 problems:

- if you use `for` to loop through a iterable, you should not change it inside the loop.
- to `del` from list you should use index.

Try this:

```
index = 0
while index < len(self.container):
    delete = raw_input("what number task would you like to delete")
    if delete == "y":
        del self.container[index]
    else:
        index += 1
```

Comment: thanks mate, I tried making your code so it was interactive e.g the user can input the task number to delete but couldn't get it to work

Comment: @Street Any error message? I guess you forgot to convert `str()` to `int()` when passing index?

Comment: see edit above, Ive had multiple attempts over the past 2 days and cant get the logic quite right. I have posted the simplest version, any suggestions? I ungreened your post so others could see its unanswered, will put it back after. cheers

Comment: never mind, after posting my edit(will delete it to avoid spam) something clicked and it now works perfect, thanks for your help :)